# instantiate a viewController func in appDelegate in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, background, appdelegate

I am new to swift iOS and I am not able to call a func in view controller from AppDelegate to activate at certain point in background in macOS bigsur

In my appDelegate I have below the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // new notifications from background
   .myNotifications() // a func in called in my viewController
    
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add some code showing how have you coded the function in your view controller as the error could be due to numerous possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the func from an initiation of your view controller instead

```
YourViewController().myNotifications()
```

Comment: I got the following error below when I tried to call the above:

Comment: Instance member 'myNotifications' cannot be used on type 'viewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: Can you provide the class you call the function from?

Comment: class viewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,  CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: class viewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate {                                                                                                             @objc func .myNotifications() {
                 }
    }